# How to pass parameter to custom form textpattern

Tags: html, textpattern

I'm building custom form in textpattern:

```
<a href="<txp:image_url id="" />" rel="lightbox"><img src="<txp:image_url id="" width="" height="" />" /></a>
```

Call this form in code:

```
<txtp:output_from form="litebox_wihtout_thumb" />
```

But i have pass parameters: id, width and height. How do it?

Answer (score 0):

I personally deal with this through php, Eg.

```
<?php
    $id = "xxx";
    $width = "xxx";
    $height = "xxx";
?>
```

Next. `<a href="<txp:image_url id="<?php echo $id> />" rel="lightbox"><img src="<txp:image_url id="<?php echo $id>" width="<?php echo $width>" height="<?php echo $height>" />" /></a>`

Comment: If a lot of images? All will have the same id. But id is unique for every image

Comment: where is save "id" in SQL?